# Check if In App Purchasing is disabled at device

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

A user can add restrictions in his device settings to disable In App Purchasing.
In that case, when trying to purchase, the operating system will popup an alert saying its disabled. 
I want to check if In App Purchasing is enabled/disabled as soon as the user launches the app and not wait for the user's purchase attempt. Is it possible to check this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
guard SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() else {
    print("Can not make payments on this device")
    return
}
```

From documentation:

```
// NO if this device is not able or allowed to make payments
@available(iOS 3.0, *)
open class func canMakePayments() -> Bool
```

More info below this [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506139-canmakepayments). If you prefer objc there is objc example too.